# Where can one find the penalty per state for a particular drug crime?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, reference-request, sentencing

Are the sentencing guidelines for each US state available in some consolidated tabular form?

I want to be able to easily compare the crimes and their penalties across states to try to identify any differences.

Comment: @jimsug Thanks for editing and providing a better clarification of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think so, if by tabular form you mean a book. I've read papers that have that information (famous study on weight of the carrier laws and one on crack sentencing disparity between federal and state charging mechanisms. At least not one that i've ever seen. This would not be a very useful database or book to compile, as it would need to be constantly updated as laws change. You'd have to look at each state's (and the federal) criminal code that you want to compare and go from there. They are all searchable databases though, on the flip side, so this is fairly easy data to compile. Try findlaw if you don't have Lexis or West. Or, if you want to use lexis or West, any law library will have computers that have it on there for free public use.